# How to use mapply/sapply/lapply to run st_distance in R

Tags: r, lapply, r-sf, sapply, mapply

I have two sf points datasets (let's say DtA and DtB). I want to use the function st_distance to measure the straight line distance between each point in DtA and each point in DtB. For example, DtA have 3 points and DtB have 2 points. It should get 6 pairs of distance results. But I know st_distance could only measure one point in DtA each time.

Does anyone know how to use mapply/sapply/lapply to measure all the points in DtA one time with st_distance? Many thanks!

I have big data. Using the loop is very slow. My loop is as below:

```
df <- c()
  for (i in 1:nrow(DtA)) {
    dist = st_distance(DtA[i,], DtB, by_element=TRUE)
    dist <- as.numeric(as.character(dist))
    df <- rbind(df, dist)  
  }
```

I want to change the above loop into an apply function. Many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You dont need to do it row by row just do it all at once - `st_distance(DtA, DtB)` returns distance matrix.

Comment: I did it all at once. But it shows "Warning message:
In mapply(st_distance, x, y, by_element = FALSE, which = which,  :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter". And only returns the results of first record in DtA. @det

Comment: Many thanks for the help! It was my fault. I should not do it row by row. I should just do it all at once using two data frames. @det

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

I have created some dummy data trying to resemble yours :

```
library(sp)
library(sf)

# dummy big data 10k points in Dta, 3 points in DtB
df = data.frame(x = rep(13.637398,10*1000), y = rep(41.30736, 10*100))
DtA = SpatialPoints(cbind(df$x, df$y), proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
DtA = st_as_sf(DtA)
DtB =  SpatialPoints(cbind(df$x[c(1:3)], df$y[c(1:3)]),proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
DtB = st_as_sf(DtB)
```

```
dists <- list()
for (i in 1:length(DtB$geometry)) {
 dists[[i]] <- st_distance(DtA, DtB[i,], by_element=TRUE)
}
```

To retrieve the distance of DtA point to DtB point:

```
n_DtA_point = 500
n_DtB_point = 2 
dists[[n_DtB_point]][n_DtA_point]
```

output:

```
0 [m]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

If you need to stick to loop/apply approach you can do the following. That would be in fact a problem of looping, not a specific spatial one:

```r
library(sf)

# Fake data
library(giscoR)

points <- gisco_get_nuts(spatialtype = "LB")
DtA <- points[sample(seq_len(nrow(points)), 132), ]
DtB <- points[sample(seq_len(nrow(points)), 921), ]

# End of fake data

# lapply approach

distend <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(DtA)), function(x){
  dist = st_distance(DtA[x,], DtB, by_element=TRUE)
  dist <- as.numeric(as.character(dist))
  return(dist)
})

# List to matrix
distend2 <- do.call("rbind", distend)

dim(distend2)
#> [1] 132 921
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Initial answer

Expanding the comment of @det, you can do it with `st_distance()`:

```r
library(sf)
# Fake data
library(giscoR)

points <- gisco_get_nuts(spatialtype = "LB")
DtA <- points[sample(seq_len(nrow(points)), 132), ]
DtB <- points[sample(seq_len(nrow(points)), 921), ]

# End of fake data


# Distances from DtA to DtB
dist <- st_distance(DtA, DtB)
dim(dist)
#> [1] 132 921

# A matrix with the right dimensions
```

As an extra, you can manipulate this a bit to get a long version of the matrix using the `tidyverse` approach:

```r
# If you need to manipulate with tidyverse...
library(tidyverse)

tib <- as_tibble(dist)

# Ids of DtB as colnames
names(tib) <- DtB$NUTS_ID

# Ids of DtA on the first column
finaltib <- DtA %>%
  st_drop_geometry() %>%
  mutate(ids_DtA = NUTS_ID) %>%
  select(ids_DtA) %>%
  bind_cols(tib) %>%
  as_tibble()

finaltib
#> # A tibble: 132 x 922
#>    ids_DtA  DE25C  CH065  FRC13  UKJ44  ITH10   DE93  ES113   HU32  DE277   ITH2
#>    <chr>      [m]    [m]    [m]    [m]    [m]    [m]    [m]    [m]    [m]    [m]
#>  1 RO421   8.68e5 1.02e6 1.32e6 1.60e6 7.92e5 1.13e6 2.37e6 1.50e5 8.82e5 8.38e5
#>  2 ES431   1.78e6 1.50e6 1.25e6 1.51e6 1.69e6 2.02e6 4.18e5 2.42e6 1.73e6 1.62e6
#>  3 BE334   4.48e5 4.77e5 4.50e5 2.94e5 6.34e5 4.21e5 1.36e6 1.22e6 4.48e5 6.55e5
#>  4 BE241   5.14e5 5.23e5 4.58e5 2.26e5 6.92e5 4.68e5 1.32e6 1.29e6 5.12e5 7.08e5
#>  5 HU222   4.79e5 6.29e5 9.27e5 1.22e6 4.06e5 8.06e5 1.99e6 3.51e5 4.89e5 4.62e5
#>  6 FI19    1.68e6 1.96e6 2.12e6 1.84e6 1.90e6 1.31e6 3.04e6 1.65e6 1.73e6 1.98e6
#>  7 TR90    2.42e6 2.58e6 2.87e6 3.15e6 2.35e6 2.60e6 3.89e6 1.64e6 2.44e6 2.39e6
#>  8 DEE0C   3.18e5 5.93e5 7.75e5 7.34e5 5.72e5 1.68e5 1.80e6 8.42e5 3.72e5 6.38e5
#>  9 PT187   1.89e6 1.62e6 1.35e6 1.56e6 1.81e6 2.11e6 3.92e5 2.55e6 1.84e6 1.74e6
#> 10 DED5    2.88e5 5.80e5 7.91e5 8.05e5 5.25e5 2.55e5 1.84e6 7.54e5 3.45e5 5.96e5
#> # ... with 122 more rows, and 911 more variables: DE114 [m], SE231 [m],
#> #   DE40A [m], TRA11 [m], DE932 [m], ES613 [m], DEA59 [m], UKD62 [m],
#> #   SE213 [m], HR04A [m], HU120 [m], DE256 [m], ITI32 [m], TR905 [m],
#> #   UKJ11 [m], BE24 [m], PL715 [m], ITF43 [m], BG342 [m], ITG17 [m], DE118 [m],
#> #   LT01 [m], SE22 [m], DE25B [m], MK006 [m], DEA38 [m], TR621 [m], UKJ27 [m],
#> #   UKJ41 [m], RO313 [m], RO123 [m], ES7 [m], DEB3J [m], FRY4 [m], AT130 [m],
#> #   DEG0H [m], RS [m], ITC15 [m], DE269 [m], ES63 [m], PT186 [m], ...

# Make it longer
finaltib_long <- finaltib %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -(ids_DtA), names_to = "ids_DtB")

finaltib_long
#> # A tibble: 121,572 x 3
#>    ids_DtA ids_DtB    value
#>    <chr>   <chr>        [m]
#>  1 BE353   ES5      944805.
#>  2 BE353   UKG1     521480.
#>  3 BE353   FRJ28    719087.
#>  4 BE353   FI1C    1793053.
#>  5 BE353   DK05     866304.
#>  6 BE353   CH01     488356.
#>  7 BE353   MT001   1774618.
#>  8 BE353   RS223   1508833.
#>  9 BE353   NL226    214993.
#> 10 BE353   FRG04    396129.
#> # ... with 121,562 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did it all at once. But it shows "Warning message: In mapply(st_distance, x, y, by_element = FALSE, which = which, : longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter". And only returns the results of first record in DtA.

Comment: It might be that something is not ok on your data, hard to say without having access to it

Comment: I updated the answer using lapply, that is exactly what you asked. Hope this works for you

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! It was my fault. I should not do it row by row. I should just do it all at once using two data frames. Many thanks!